# Get all post embedded images

Tags: attachments

i want to get a post embedded images but the only methods i see over the internet are

```
        $attachments = get_posts(array(
            'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type'         => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page'    => $n,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ));


        $attachments = get_children(array(
            'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type'         => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page'    => $n,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ));

        $attachments = get_attached_media('image', get_the_ID());
```

but this gives only the attached images i want all the images in a post even if they are not attached to that post `'post_parent' => get_the_ID()`

i think this is the wordpress way of attaching images it sounds like a one-to-many relationship
an image can only be attached to one post

any idea ? thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean all embedded images from post content, maybe you can try a regex in post content to search all images. Also you should look for all post meta in a same way. But if any post meta has attachment ID instead of URL, it can be quite impossible unless you explicitly know which meta key contains an attachment ID.

Answer (score 1):

i think if WordPress doesn't provide such a function then this is the shortest way

```
function my_get_embeded_media() {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());

    $arr = preg_match_all("/<img[^>]* src=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>/", $content, $matches);

    return $arr ? $matches[1] : array();
}
```

but we still can't control the images size!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument to get every image from any page:

```
function testingdom(){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('https://the_post_url.com/anyone');
    $data = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
    
    $srcs = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $dat){
        $srcs[] =  $data->item($key)->getAttribute("src");
    }
    
    $dom = null;

}
add_action("wp_head", "testingdom");
```

This way you should have every src in an array called `srcs`

Comment: yeah this might work and you can also select them via some regex i'm just wondring if there is a wordpress function that could do the job

Comment: Dont think so, maybe you can create a function to get_post / post_content and look for every src